# SRS configure error in Mac pro m1 (arm64 cpu)- ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: simple-realtime-server

Operation on 'Mac M1 pro' which cpu is arm64 architecture.

on srs branch: **`4.0release`**

do

```
cd trunk
./configure --osx
```

Get error as below:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [apps/openssl] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Build openssl-1.1-fit failed.
```

Log is:

```
User config: --osx
Detail config: --prefix=/usr/local/srs --config=conf/srs.conf --hls=on --hds=off --dvr=on --ssl=on --https=on --ssl-1-0=off --ssl-local=off --sys-ssl=off --transcode=on --ingest=on --stat=on --http-callback=on --http-server=on --stream-caster=on --http-api=on --utest=off --cherrypy=off --srt=off --rtc=on --simulator=off --cxx11=off --cxx14=off --ffmpeg-fit=on --nasm=on --srtp-nasm=on --clean=on --gperf=off --gmc=off --gmd=off --gmp=off --gcp=off --gprof=off --static=off --shared-st=off --shared-srt=off --shared-ffmpeg=off --log-verbose=off --log-info=off --log-trace=on --gcov=off --debug=off --debug-stats=off --cross-build=off --cc=gcc --cxx=g++ --ar=ar --ld=gcc --randlib=randlib
SRS_WORKDIR: ., SRS_OBJS_DIR: objs, SRS_OBJS: ./objs, SRS_PLATFORM: Platform-Darwin-21.2.0-Clang13.1.6-SRS4-arm64
Alias python2 as python
Checking gcc/g++/gdb/make.
Required tools are ok.
OSX detected, install tools if needed
OSX install tools success
SED is sed_utility
The state-threads is ok.
Building openssl-1.1-fit.
Operating system: i686-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:28:41 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1b (0x1010102fL) for darwin-i386-cc
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

...
gcc  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch i386 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/hangwu/git/srs/trunk/objs/Platform-Darwin-21.2.0-Clang13.1.6-SRS4-arm64/openssl-1.1-fit/_release/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/hangwu/git/srs/trunk/objs/Platform-Darwin-21.2.0-Clang13.1.6-SRS4-arm64/openssl-1.1-fit/_release/lib/engines-1.1\"" -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_NO_HEARTBEATS -MMD -MF apps/app_rand.d.tmp -MT apps/app_rand.o -c -o apps/app_rand.o apps/app_rand.c

...



ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [apps/openssl] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
Build openssl-1.1-fit failed.
```

What's the possible reason for this error?
Is there any way to avoid it?

**It seems the gcc config param '-arch i386' is not right for my environment, is it the root cause of this error?**

Answer (score 0):

Now, at 2022.08.22, Apple M1 is ok to build and run SRS 5.0. Please see issue [M1: Not possible to build on Apple Silicon](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/2747) for detail.

We have the docker images for `linux/arm/v7` and `linux/arm64/v8`, it should work on `Apple M1` also, see [#3058](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/3058).

Aside from openssl build issue, we also adopt the ST(state-threads) for Apple M1. Apart from the ST(state-threads) adaption, the configure script was updated to identify M1.

ST also is avaialble for Apple M1 now, please see [#22](https://github.com/ossrs/state-threads/issues/22).